# Trouble with PhoneGap demo: "nothing to be done for..."

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to do the PhoneGap demo for IOS at:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/phonegap-development/

It says to open a terminal in the folder that has "PhoneGapLibInstaller.pkg". I did that. If I do "ls", I can see the file listed. Then it says to run "make". I'm not a terminal person very much, but it first said "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop." I assumed the tutorial left out the file name so I tried "make PhoneGapLibInstaller.pkg". Now I get "make: Nothing to be done for `PhoneGapLibInstaller.pkg'."

What should I be typing?? I wish tutorials would be more clear sometimes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following the install instructions on the PhoneGap Wiki for iOS?

[Getting Started with PhoneGap (iOS)](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494778/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-%28iOS%29)

Comment: If you go to the wiki, the page is missing:

Comment: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/404/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-%28iPhone%29

The page you were looking for was not found

Sorry, but we couldn't find what you were looking for. Usually, this happens when a page has been renamed or deleted and the link you followed points to the old name.

Comment: Oh, your link works, but the link from the homepage does not:

Comment: Yes, I did start that, but it was the demo above that is not working. I got the package installed by clicking it, not by running make, and the HTML files are nowhere I can find them. So XCode works with PhoneGap installed, but the files I thought might show up using the "make" command are seemingly missing.

Comment: http://wiki.phonegap.com/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-(iPhone)

that is the page that is 404, btw...

Comment: If you can get a basic 'Hello World' working by following the wiki page, then it may be that the demo page is out of date and 'make' isn't necessary.

Comment: That could be! I have "hello world" already working after finishing the provision for the my iPod Touch. Thanks!